# Is it possible to insert working javascript with both "<" and ">" removed?

Tags: javascript, signalr, code-injection

I'm working on a basic chat application and what to be able to render out some html tags to, which is done at the server level.  However, I don't want chatters to be able to add any of their own valid HTML markup for the sake of javascript injection.

Since I'm not concerned with keeping my user's CSS styling at all, is it sufficient for me to prevent javascript injection and other malicious attacks by removing all '<' and '>' characters on the server as soon as it is received, and then add in my own html markup later?  I know that some browsers try to make a best guess and will add a closing '>' when it thinks it is needed, but I am hoping that cleaning out all '<' will stop that from happening.

Thanks!

Comment: So you worry about XSS? Have a look [at this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: and this: https://xss-game.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

It should be sufficient to replace any `<`s and `>`s. You can also do better than just removing them - replacing them `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively will allow you to safely print the characters. Try something like this:

```
function html_escape_string(str) {
    return str.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `Microsoft.Security.Application;` to my using statements on my chat hub and then used `Encoder.HtmlEncode(data)` where data is my message being sent. It displays the tags as text.